# moving commits to new branch with git rebase

Tags: git

I'm struggeling with branches in Git and fail to attribute them properly to commits. The newest two commits ended up in different branches (one in master, one in pm/gitrev) - but need them both to be on top of eachother in the same feature-branch (e.g. something new, like pm/git-version) which I can push to the remote repositor 'pm' so that I can create on GitHub a proper pull-request for origin/master.

My currently history is completely linear and looks like:

```
$ git log --graph --pretty=format:"%h %d %s %n" -4
* 02f82ee  (HEAD -> git-version, pm/gitrev) Fail gracefully when operating on detached head 
| 
* 998d969  (pm/master, master) Change: Adopt the versioning scheme now with git 
| 
* c95db24  (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Added tag 0.4.5 for changeset e115586dd0a0 
| 
* 3418735  (tag: 0.4.5) Update: Changelog for release
```

I created a new branch, based on 998d969 (master) and rebased the other two onto it, e.g. by `git rebase -b master git-version`. Yet my history is linear, but commits didn't change their branch as assume they should.

What do I miss with `git rebase`? How do I remove all branch info from the top most commits and move them to their joint, but new branch, based on origin/master?

I can re-write history of the remote repo 'pm'.

Comment: What do you mean by "Yet my history is linear, but commits didn't change their branch as assume they should."?

Comment: linear history: I clarified the log output by using graph: all commits are sequentially, including the two newest, though they are in different branches. "Didn't change branches as they should": My aim is to move the two newest commits to one (new) branch. And have them removed from their current ones.

Comment: You can use `cherry-pick` to pick those commits on to the branch you desire. After that remove them from master, and I think you should have what you wanted.

Comment: Very much so! That is basically what I was looking for. Thanks! Now I have to get rid of the "old" commits... but I guess that can be done separately and more easily

Comment: You can achieve that using `git reset --hard commit-you-want-it-to-reset-to` (Beware, this will change the head of that branch, can be recovered using `reflog` though).

Answer (score 4):

To move commits to a other branch you can use the command `git cherry-pick`:

```
git cherry-pick <commit-hash>
```

You can get the commit-hash in the log of the original commit branch:

```
git log
```